# How to pass value of a HTML column into textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table fetching values dynamically from the database and I have used the sum function to calculate the sum of entire column.

These are my columns where I am fetching the sum total of a column

```
<td id="totalValue13" style="background-color: darkseagreen;"></td>
<td id="totalValue11" style="background-color: darkseagreen;"></td>
<td id="totalValue12" style="background-color: darkseagreen;"></td>
```

I want to pass the value of these `<td>`s into a textbox where I want to calculate these three values. I am using JavaScript to calculate it, given below is a JavaScript code for calculations:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var el, i = 0, total = 0; 
        while (el = document.getElementById('v'+(i++))) {
            el.value = el.value.replace(/\\D/, ""); 
            total = total + Number(el.value); 
        }
        result.value = total; 

        if (document.getElementById('v0').value == "" && document.getElementById('v1').value == "" && document.getElementById('v2').value == "") {
            result.value = ""; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

I just want to know how to pass the id of an HTML table column here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value` since table cells don't have a value. Here is an example on how to calculate the sum of given table cells with each having a separate `id`.

```js
function calculate()
{
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var v1 = document.getElementById('totalValue11');
  var v2 = document.getElementById('totalValue12');
  var v3 = document.getElementById('totalValue13');
  var el, sum = 0;
  
  var inputList = [v1,v2,v3];
  
  for(var i=0; i<inputList.length; i++)
  {
    el = inputList[i];
    if(el.innerHTML != '' && !isNaN(el.innerHTML))
    {
      sum += parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    }
  }
  result.value = sum;  // If needed to write to cell use result.innerHTML = sum;
}


// Call it whenever you like
calculate();
```

```css
td
{
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="totalValue13">5</td>
  <td id="totalValue11">3</td>
  <td id="totalValue12">25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><label for="result">Result:</label><input type="text" id="result" value="" readonly="readonly"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```